# How to restrict linux user to absolute minimal commands for SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy

I have a linux box set up, and I have a user that I would like to use for a proxy only. That is, someone would SSH in with this user and do dynamic SOCKS5 port forwarding to their localhost, and then use that tunnel as a proxy for whatever they need on their system.

My question is, is there any simple way to make it so that this user can't do anything BUT use it as a proxy? i.e. make it so that once a user has connected with SSH, they can't run any commands at all on the remote computer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with permissible commands in the `authorized_keys` file.

user would not log in via ssh but will have a restricted set of commands that would only be allowed to execute via ssh, for example `"ssh somehost bin/programname"`

more details [here](http://david-latham.blogspot.in/2013/12/restrict-commands-executed-via-pre.html) and [here](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8257)

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but I found an already answered question with a much, much simpler solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code for creating limited access user for socks5 proxy only.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo -n "Enter username: "
read usernamee;

cd /tmp/
useradd $usernamee -m -d /home/$usernamee -s /bin/rbash
passwd $usernamee
cd /home/$usernamee/
echo 'PATH=""' >> /home/$usernamee/.profile
chmod 555 /home/$usernamee/
chmod 444 .bash_logout .bashrc .profile
```

just create shell script and make it executable

```
chmod +x shell.sh
```